# If a graph is not 3-COLORable, then there are at most 2 Independant Sets in G?

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete

Assuming $G=(V,E)$ is a 3-colorable graph, then there are 3 disjoint independent subsets of $V$: $S_1,S_2,S_3$ such that $S_1 \cup S_2 \cup S_3=V$, by taking each $S_i$ to include the vertices of color $i$.

I wanted to know - if $G$ is not 3-colorable, then can it has 3 disjoint subsets that their union is $V$?

I think it can't be by the definition of 3-colorable.

Am I correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like homework, so you should try to prove it.  The title, by the way, doesn't make sense.

**Proof sketch.** Suppose that you can partition the vertex set into three independent sets, $S_1, S_2, S_3$.  Color the vertices in partition $S_1$ red, $S_2$ green, and $S_3$ blue.

**Claim.**  This is a proper coloring, hence the graph is 3-colorable.

We conclude that *if* the graph is 3-colorable, *then* its vertex set can be partitioned into three independent sets.

Comment: Thank you very much! It is actually something that I thought of by myself, I just needed a verification. :)